Unable to pass required argument to parent class using super
After super method in the child class, I am unable to pass a parameter value to the parent class.
void main() {
      MobilePhone mp = new MobilePhone(modelName: "7T", brandName: "OnePlus");
    }

class Electronics {
  //parent class
  double height = 56;
  double width = 56;
  double thickness = 56;

  Electronics({required String brandName}) {
    print("The Brand Name of this Mobile Phone is - $brandName");
  }
}

class MobilePhone extends Electronics {
  //child class
  MobilePhone({required String modelName, required String brandName})
      : super(brandName) {
    print("The model of this mobile phone is - $modelName");
  }
}

Compile Error:
main.dart:19:14: Error: Too many positional arguments: 0 allowed, but 1 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments.
      : super(brandName) {

Thanks in advance!

Since your super call contains a required named argument, you need to provide that name when calling super():
You can either do:
  MobilePhone({required String modelName, required String brandName})
      : super(brandName: brandName) {
    print("The model of this mobile phone is - $modelName");
  }

But you can also do the following using super-parameters which are basically a shorthand which does the same:
  MobilePhone({required String modelName, required super.brandName}) {
    print("The model of this mobile phone is - $modelName");
  }

